# Difference in handling HTML and JSP by servlet filter in WildFly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, wildfly, servlet-filters

I have a simple static HTML file and simple servlet filter which add header and footer to content

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HeaderFooterFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeaderFooterFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("Filter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Adding header and footer");

        servletResponse.getWriter().println("<h1>Header from filter</h1><hr>");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        servletResponse.getWriter().println("<hr><p>Footer from filter</p>");

        logger.info("End of filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.info("Filter destroy");
    }
}
```

HTML contains one line

```
<p>Some static content</p>
```

The problem is that I see footer which was added by filter only if the extension of the static file is jsp but not html. The header is added to the resulting page in both situations. I guess that html and jsp handled by the container differently but want to find a more detailed answer of why I got such strange behavior.

The filter mapping is "/*". I use WildFly to deploy the application.

UPD. Just tried to deploy the same app to TomCat and it works correctly.

Comment: I can't tell you why this is happening, but I _can_ say that using Thymeleaf with the Layout Dialect (or Tiles if you have to stick with JSP, which is seriously aging) will be a lot simpler and cleaner.

Comment: You are right but I need to investigate this situation for some reasons.